# Source tree is not launching External merge tool when I choose to resolve conflict using external merge tool

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, mergetool, filemerge

Source tree is not launching external merge tool for few files with extension .java . Source tree is showing conflicts in few files. When I select resolve conflict -> Launch external merge tool, it just shows a popup for less then one second and dismiss. Instead of opening the tool it generates and shows 4 backup files below conflicted file in source tree. I have checked .gitconfig too and it shows correct path there mapped to opendiff which opens FileMerge by default in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen due to Sourcetree couldn't fine '.gitconfig' file location. Even if you keep 'Allow Sourcetree to modify your global Git config files' check box ticked. it may not be updated.

Try adding, HOME in your system environment variables to the path of your '.gitconfig' file location. For e.g. HOME C:\Users\XXX

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I am trying this on mac and having Xcode. It was not showing anything under command line tools. I installed command line tools and mapped under Xcode. Also changed the diff to FileMerge in Sourcetree preferences. And now i am getting my External merge tool launched.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode go to preferences >> locations >> Command line tools >> choose one xcode

Comment: This was the issue for me. Xcode had a "No Xcode Selected" message in Preferences. There was only one option (and it was already selected in the popup button), but by selecting it again the message changed to show my Xcode install as "selected". SoureTree External diff works now.